# Multithreaded background worker design

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, silverlight, timer

Not being experienced in multi-threaded programming or technologies, I would like to ask this question as a way to focus a design to accomplish the following requirements for relatively long running jobs (between 4 and 10 seconds) that are launched in real time by some user action:

1. After the job is initiated and until it completes:

     * Show some indeterminate progress indicator (ie, spinning ball, progress bar)

     * Show a running count of the elapsed number of seconds as part of a status update

   Use an MVVM design with the status and notion of IsBusy being data bound properties in some INPC view model class

   Unit testable

I started down the path of trying to use a BackgroundWorker that is either subclassed or otherwise encapsulated, but found myself getting tripped up on how to synchronize the notion of counting the elapsed seconds on a timer thread while another thread is doing the work.

Design ideas that might lead to more focused programming questions much appreciated!

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: Your user already knows how many seconds passed, she counted the number of times she tapped her foot.  Not always accurate, she taps faster on a busy day.  Don't show her something she already knows.  If you don't know how long it will take, which is common, then just display the "I'm working on it, not dead" animation.  You could implement FreeCell on your loading screen but she already knows how to start that.

Comment: Why not simply record the starting time of the backgroundworker in the subclassed class and deduct it from the current time? Backgroundworker sounds about right. Be sure to use Dispatcher when you update the UI

Comment: Hi Hans, you know that users want what they want, even though you know better. Especially when they are female!

Comment: @Mattias. Agreed if the goal was just to show the final elapsed time, but I want to update the status every second. Cheers

Comment: I don't see the problem... just have update status thread that polls the elapsed time from the backgroundworker :)

Comment: @Mattias. You mean from worker.ProgressChanged?

Comment: No, just use one backgroundworker for doing the actual work, and another to poll the one for the progress and elapsed time through properties you expose and then display them

Comment: Two workers?? can you post some quick pigeon code so I get the idea? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DispatcherTimer to update a ElapsedTime property in your view model. This is called from the GUI thread so you can directly bind to the property. Use a BackgroundWorker to perform your thread task.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged  
{
  public DateTime ElapsedTime {get; private set;}
  public bool IsRunning {get; private set;}

  private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  private DateTime startTime;
  private DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();

  public ViewModel()
  {
    t.Interval = 500; 
    t.Tick += (ox,ex) => UpdateTime();
    worker.DoWork += YourMethodHere;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (ox,ex)=> {
      IsRunning = false;
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsRunning"));
    };
  }

  public void UpdateTime()
  {
     ElapsedTime=startTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ElapsedTime"));
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    startTime=DateTime.Now;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    IsRunning = true;
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsRunning"));
  }
```

}

You can bind the progress bar GUI element to a bool property in your view model which is updated when started and finishing your background task (use the RunWorkerComplete event).

Comment: Hi Guy. Are you assuming that inpc is being fired on IsRunning & ElapsedTime? How about showing an updated Status property every second, would you do that from a worker.ProgressChanged delegate? Cheers

Comment: No, the UpdateTime method is called every 500ms from the dispatcher (GUI) thread, and keeps the ElapsedTime property correct. You only need the ProgressChanged delegate if the progress you are showing relies on the state of the background thread in some way.

Answer (score 2):

The `BackgroundWorker` class is a great tool for kicking off background tasks, but its design forces developers down the wrong path sometimes regarding how the UI should be updated. The problem is that it uses the push model for updating the UI. In other words, the `ReportProgress` and `ProgressChanged` members are designed to marshal the event handler onto the UI thread. That is fine for many situations, but in <strike>most</strike> other cases it does not work so well...as you have noticed.

An alternate strategy for updating the UI is to have the UI thread poll a shared data structure periodically for the progress information. The worker thread will publish new progress information to this shared data structure and the UI thread will pick it up on its own schedule. This has several advantages.

- It breaks the tight coupling between the UI and worker threads that `Control.Invoke` imposes.
- It puts the responsibility of updating the UI thread on the UI thread where it should belong anyway.
- The UI thread gets to dictate when and how often the update should take place.
- There is no risk of the UI message pump being overrun as would be the case with the marshaling techniques initiated by the worker thread.
- The worker thread does not have to wait for an acknowledgement that the update was performed before proceeding with its next steps (ie. you get more throughput on both the UI and worker threads).
- It is a lot easier to implement the MVVM `IsBusy` data bound property.

You will have to scrap the `BackgroundWorker` class and manually start a new thread (or use the `ThreadPool`) if you want to switch to the polling method.

Comment: Have you got any links and/or quick code example to show how the worker thread is synchronized to the ui thread? Is the DispatchTimer the timer to use? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with my worker threads using callback methods to update collections in the UI thread that hold progress and messages, and using a separate timer in the UI thread to update the UI. Use locking around the collections to mind concurrency. The callbacks also return a continue/stop flag to the worker threads for graceful shutdown control.